# Regular expression that matches 3 characters anywhere in the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression that matches for example ap**3 or **1*2*3 or 12****r. So far i have this regular expression: `/[a-z0-9]{3}/g`, but this only matches 3 characters that are next to one another. Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: Should it be exactly 3 alphanumeric characters or at least 3?

Comment: What do you mean by "for example ap**3 or 1*2*3 or 12**r"?  Are those literal asterisks or wildcars for "anything goes here"?  Are you looking for three specific characters but you don't care where they are in the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^(?=(\W*\w){3}).*$/
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FFK9H/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex like this:

`(?=.*A)(?=.*B)(?=.*C)`

when You need A, B and C all in the same time anywhere in the string,
just replace those letters with Yours characters.
Or maybe You just need this regex:

`[^\*]`

Please explain more about Your needs.